# Multiple column selection using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the below SQL query. Not sure how to convert this to Linq.

```
select u.userid, u.firstname, u.lastname,companyname,city,state 
from user u 
order by  u.lastname, u.firstname
```

I've tried this:

```
public ActionResult Users() {
  dbEntities entities1 = new dbEntities();
  return View(from users in entities1.u_user select userid,firstname,lastname,companyname,city,state);
}
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: What language - C# or VB.Net?

Comment: @glennsl Thanks! I tried something like this:  public ActionResult Users()
        {
            dbEntities entities1 = new dbEntities();
            return View(from users in entities1.u_user
                        select userid,firstname,lastname,companyname,city,state);
        }

Comment: @luv2code I've put the code in the question, where it belongs :) You need to approve the edit though (or wait for reviewers to approve it)

Comment: You should also be more specific about why this doesn't work.

Comment: @glennsl I approved it.

Answer (score 0):

The exact translation is :

```
Db.User.Select(p=> new {
    userid = p.userId,
    firstName = p.firstName,
    lastName = p.lastName,
    companyName p = p.companyName,
    city = p.City,
    state = p.State }).OrderBy(p=>p.lastName).ThenBy(p=>p.firstName)
```

Where you create a dynamic `object` containing only some fields you want.

If you want all properties of your entity, you can use simply :

```
Db.User.OrderBy(p=>p.lastName).ThenBy(p=>p.firstName)
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, assuming C#, convert SQL to LINQ by converting phrases in LINQ comprehension syntax order, and if SQL has table aliases, use them in LINQ as range variables. Convert non-range functions like `TOP` or `DISTINCT` as function calls outside the rest of the expression.

```
var ans = from u in user
          orderby u.lastname, u.firstname
          select new { u.userid, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.companyname, u.city, u.state };
```